# C++ optimization - stack allocated array type with externally linked dimension?

Tags: c++, arrays, optimization

I'm new to optimization in C++. I have read that stack allocated memory can be much faster than heap allocated memory.

I also have read that std::array is stack allocated, but most other containers, like std::vector or dynamic arrays are heap allocated. I'd like to define a class which essentially just stores an array of doubles. I intend for all instances of the class to have the same dimension, and that I can calculate what that dimension will be at compile time. The catch is that I would like to do the computation of that dimension in main.cpp instead of in the class.cpp. That means trying something like the following:

```
class.h:
extern constexpr dimension;
```

and,

```
class.cpp:
class Coordinates {
    public std::array<double, dimension> q{}; 
}
```

and then

```
main.cpp:
#include "class.h"
constexpr dimension = 2*3*100
```

Now, `extern constexpr dimension` is nonsense as the translation unit will not know what the value of dimension is at compile time.

Is there a way to have a stack-allocated array type object with dimension defined in another translation unit? Would it even be worth it?

Comment: How about vector with stack allocator? Using alloca()?

Comment: Best thing I can think of is `main` allocates the array, since only it knows the size, and provides it to the object on construction. I think you're stuck on this one.

Comment: I strongly doubt std::array is stack allocated because you would have to somehow pass the result of alloca() to the std::array<> object. Where did you hear such information? That being said you can stack allocate almost anything with the correct in-place constructor and alloca(). STL doesn't support stack allocation because it is a very dangerous practice.

Comment: `std::array` can be allocated anywhere. Could be stack, could be static storage, could be dynamic storage (`new std::array<>`)

Comment: Sheeeooot. I'm dumb. Can you make `Coordinates` a template?

Comment: "I intend for all instances of the class to have the same dimension" then use template<int dimension> class Coordinates{}

Comment: Aside: You've just found one of the reasons using stack and heap instead of automatic and dynamic can cause problems.

Comment: Before you go wild with performance tuning, the first step is to benchmark

Comment: @DavidBien I found the remark about stack allocation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39549597/15488679) Are you referring to stack overflow when you say allocating to the stack is dangerous, or pointers going out of scope, or something else?

Comment: @denomme Oh, ok, I misunderstood. All the means is that std::array<>, since it is a fixed-size array, doesn't allocate dynamic memory internally.  So if you declare it as a local, then all of its memory is in the stack. This doesn't use alloca() - this is just how local variables work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for a template:

```
template<int dimension>
struct Coordinates {
    std::array<double, dimension> q{}; 
};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr auto dimension = 2*3*100;
    Coordinates<dimension> c;
    c.q[0] = 1;
    c.q[1] = 2;
    // ...
}
```

#### [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bdeo9Y1K9)

Comment: This does exactly what I was asking for! I didn't realize that templates can be non-type variables. This advantage (static allocation instead of dynamic) is pointed out in this article on the topic: [learncpp reference](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/template-non-type-parameters/)