# converting heap based vector to stack

Tags: c++

I would like to convert it to vector of vectors
but I'm confused about the code above
it's better to store it on stack rather than heap, that's why I want to change it to vector of vector

```
std::vector<DPoint*>* pixelSpacing;    ///< vector of slice pixel spacings
pixelSpacing = new std::vector<DPoint*>(volume.pixelSpacing->size());
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pixelSpacing->size(); i++)
{
   (*pixelSpacing)[i] = new DPoint(*(*volume.pixelSpacing)[i]);
}
```

Comment: I see no vector of vectors. There is usually no point to store vector itself on the heap, it already stores its elements on the heap anyway, so you are only pushing the three pointers it contains to the heap. Why store `DPoint` by pointer again? Why not just by value? You should use pointers because you need to manually manage lifetime or refer to objects, no just because they are non-primitive types, this is not Java.

Comment: You don't have any `delete`s for all your `new`s.

Comment: @ThomasWeller that's why I want to remove the new, and make vector of vectors

Comment: @Quimby Can you make an answer with the suggestions, I didn't understand it

Comment: Maybe you want [std::array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548254/does-stdarray-guarantee-allocation-on-the-stack-only)

Comment: Why a vector of vectors? This looks like a situation for a `vector<DPoint> pixelSpacing` (no pointers in the vector, no pointer to the vector)

Comment: @harold That's what I want...

Comment: @harold can you tell me the syntax of initializing it ?

Comment: Sure, here you go: [Initializing the size of a C++ vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25108854/555045)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as per the comment, I am making an answer.

```
std::vector<DPoint> pixelSpacing(volume.pixelSpacing->size()); 
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pixelSpacing.size(); i++)
{
   pixelSpacing[i] = DPoint(/*DPoint constructor args*/);
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
std::vector<DPoint> pixelSpacing;
//Reserving size is optional.
pixelSpacing.reserve(volume.pixelSpacing->size());
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < volume.pixelSpacing->size(); i++)
{
   pixelSpacing.emplace_back(/*DPoint constructor args*/);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `std::vector` is allocated on the heap. There's no way to "convert it" so that it allocates stuff on the stack. You may create a new vector-like sequence container that allocates on the stack is one thing you can do. Or you can use `std::array` which allocates on the stack by default.

Comment: The vector can be allocated on the stack. Its elements are allocated in the free store.

Comment: I want to remove the news..

Comment: Can you show me the equivelent of the above code using std::array ?